# Can't find word with Quotation mark in text file on php

Tags: php

I have a text file, and I want to check if the file contain the string `wor"dddddd`. Lets suppose that the this is the content of the the text file:

```
...,sometext,moretext,wor"dddddd,867767,3468647,sometext,...
```

Here is my code, I don't know why it doesn't work (prints 8 instead of 3):

```
    <?php
$id='wor\"dddddd';
$fopen = fopen("file.txt", 'r');
$content= htmlspecialchars(file_get_contents("file.txt"));//
$split=explode(",", $content);
$arr_len=count($split);
$pos=0;
$result=array();

//finding the position of the word in the array
foreach ($split as $x){
    if(stripos($id, $x)!==false) {
        break;}
        $pos++;
}

    echo $pos;//should print 3, but it prints 8 i.e it's not find the word wor"dddddd
        ?>
```

I don't know why if there is a Quotation mark inside the word it doesn't find it, I tried to add the backslash `\` (line 2 in my code) as you can see, but still the output is 8. what should I do, if I know that the word that I want to find In the text file contains Quotation mark?

Comment: There's no need to escape `"` in a single-qouted string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here you have a couple or errors.

First, in string

```
$id='wor\"dddddd';
```

You don't need to escape `"` in a single-quoted string. So, you're trying to find `'wor\"dddddd'` instead of `'wor"dddddd'`. It's obvious that this won't happen.

Next error comes from using `htmlspecialchars`.

This function will turn quotes to html-entities, so instead of `wor"dddddd` you will have `wor&quot;dddddd`. Again, you can find `wor"dddddd` when you have `wor&quot;dddddd`.

So, the solution:

```
$id = 'wor"dddddd';
$content= file_get_contents("file.txt");
// following lines remain unchanged
```

**Bonus:** you can replace loop over `$split` with one line:

```
$pos = array_search($id, $split);
```